# Convincing TS that an object coming through a proxy is never null

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy, proxies

I have the following fn that creates a proxy:

```
const getStorageProxy = (store?: Storage) => {
  const proxyObj: { store?: DataStorage } = {};

  return new Proxy(proxyObj, {
    get(obj, prop) {
      if (!obj.store) {
        obj.store = new DataStorage(store);
      }

      return obj.store[prop];
    },
  });
};
```

And then I export several instances of this proxy:

```
const storageA = getStorageProxy(storeA);
const storageB = getStorageProxy(storeB);

export { storageA, storageB };
```

The reason for this is that I don't want to actually instantiate the `DataStorage` class unless it's used, and for convenience I want to be able to type:

```
import { storageA } from 'storage';
```

This all works.  The problem is that according to TS both of my exported storage instances are of type `DataStorage | void` because of:

```
const proxyObj: { store?: DataStorage } = {};
```

They're actually not because of the getter in the proxy, but how do I tell this to TS without actually assigning something to `proxyObj.store` on instantiation?

Comment: Use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) if you're smarter than the compiler?  Like, `const proxyObj = {} as {store: DataStorage}` maybe?

Comment: Can you please clarify where you are seeing the `DataStorage | void` type. I tried your example and am seeing different results.